# Atomically Incrementing value in postgres table and returning the old value

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have a table in Postgresql with following columns:

```
Id      |     Index
```

I want to implement a function like:

```
int GetNextIndex(string Id)
```

The function will look up entity with `Id=Id` and increment Index then return the old value(before update). How can I atomically do this using Entity Framework in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question...  can you provide a few examples?

Comment: Ok I need a sequence on my table and I wanna be able to call nextval to get the value and increment. kinda like i++

Comment: As part of an insert, or just standalone?

Comment: No standalone. I need that value to do some operation before adding a new entity

Answer (score 0):

I may be grossly oversimplifying your task, but if all you want is the sequence, something like this should work:

```
public int GetId(string SequenceName)
{
    int result;

    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (NpgsqlCommand id = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Format(
            "select nextval('{0}')", SequenceName), conn))
            result = Convert.ToInt32(id.ExecuteScalar());

        conn.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

You should be able to adapt this if you have standalone connection objects, etc.

I may be jumping ahead here, but one of my favorite functions is the following, which takes a collection of objects and assigns a value to each "Id" field in the object (or whatever field is your ID/PK).  It's possible something like this will be suited for your task as well:

```
public void AssignSequences(string SequenceName, string PropertyName,
    IEnumerable<object> DomainObjects)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (NpgsqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (NpgsqlCommand id = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Format(
                "select nextval('{0}')", SequenceName),
                conn, trans))
            {

                foreach (object o in DomainObjects)
                {
                    PropertyInfo p = o.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);
                    p.SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt32(id.ExecuteScalar()));
                }
            }

            trans.Commit();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Which, assuming your Id field is named "Id," would look something like this:

```
AssignSequences("order_line_id", "Id", NewOrders);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am actually not using this to assign auto numbers to PK or any filed. My application is such that before creating an entity, I have to read last index in the table, use that int to do some calculations in order to create the next object and then insert it in the table. The thing is that I need next val before inserting

Comment: Gotcha -- hopefully the first method answered the mail; if not, let me know

Comment: Thank you so much! I am gonna try it and report back

Comment: @A03"read last index in the table, use that int to do some calculations..." That's not concurrency-safe. Any other user will draw the same "next" value in the mean time.

Comment: That's why I need atomic "increment and return old value". How can I do that? Is that even possible?